# issues in creating c linux library

Tags: java, c, openssl, java-native-interface, shared-libraries

Hi I am creating an openssl wrapper c library to be use with JNI. My c source file name is rsa.c and JNI header file name is OpensslRSA.h which is contain in both JAVA_HOME/include and JAVA_HOME/include/linux directories. I am using below syntax to create this library .

**gcc -shared -fpic -o librsa.so -I/usr/local/jdk1.7.0_45/include -I/usr/local/jdk1.7.0_45/include/linux rsa.c**

This c program uses below header files

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <OpensslRSA.h>
#include <openssl/pem.h>
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
#include <openssl/rsa.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <openssl/bio.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>
```

but when I use this from java program as below

**java -Djava.library.path=/home/agarwal/test/c_tests/opensslrsalib OpensslRSA**
then it give below error
**java: symbol lookup error: /home/agarwal/test/c_tests/opensslrsalib/librsa.so: undefined symbol: BIO_new_mem_buf** 
Can any body let me know what should I do for this as all the header files used exist in /usr/include as per there use in c source

Comment: Are you on Windows? If so, I don't believe is uses `JAVA_HOME` for library `PATHs`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BIO_new_mem_buf is in the openssl library. You have to link your library with `-lcrypto` (lower case L) or with what `pkg-config --libs openssl` gives you.

Comment: I link with -lcrypto it build ok, but link with static option -l:libcrypto.a, then failed

.
.
.
$ gcc -fPIC base64.c -lcrypto -shared => Build OK
.
.
.
$ gcc -fPIC base64.c -l:libcrypto.a -shared
.
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.a(bio_lib.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.str1.1' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.a: error adding symbols: Bad value

Comment: @MinhNV as this is a different error, your best option probably is to ask a new question (or use search engine of your choice to find out if someone has solved a similar problem before)